# How can I send more than one String through a POST or JSON? Can I send a JSON array through another JSON object?

Tags: php, android, json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement push notifications for android. I want to send the same message to more than one phone. Currently it works to send to one phone. I want to get the registration keys from one mysql database and send to all those phones one message.

The problem is I am confused by json and arrays and POST. Can I send a JSON array through another JSON object? How can I put in  `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId", regkeys));` more than just one registration key? I tried to make regkeys an array but it didn't work. I know it has to be somehow in the form

`{   "message":"some message here",
    "regIds": [
        "dsdfsfet366767547",
        "63567356366reygh",
        "sgdgtwetwetsdgsdg",
        "sdgsdgsdgwet24t"
    ]
}`

but I don't know how to create it.

Php code

```
     $regId = $_POST["regId"];
     $message = $_POST["message"];
...
$registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);
     $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
...
     public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {...}
```

Android code

```
 String regkeys = regkey.getText().toString();
 String message = messg.getText().toString();
```

...

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair> ();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId", regkeys));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));

JSONObject json = parser2.makeHttpRequest(url, params);
```

...

```
 public class jParser2 {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObject = null;
static String json = "";

public jParser2(){

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> params){

try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
        sb.append(line+"\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();        
}   
try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

    return jObject;
}
  }
```

My server to GCM code.

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
// include config
include_once './config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do in the Android code. I'm assuming the PHP code is used to send the GCM messages from the server. What's the purpose of the HTTP request sent from the Android code? Is it sent to your server? To GCM server?

Comment: The android code just sends the message from the phone to server and the server sends to multiple other phones.

Comment: Does the Android code send the recipient registration IDs of the message to the server too? Usually the registration IDs are stored in the server.

Comment: Yeah, currently I am just testing it so I was sending the registration IDs manually from android. The idea afterwards was to just do a mysql query get the registration keys from the server and then send them back from android to server and then to GCM together with the message.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your `$gcm->send_notification` function looks like, but it should have something like this :

```
$data = array( 'message' => 'some message' );
$ids = array( 'reg-id1', 'reg-id2' );
$payload = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $ids,
                'data'              => $data,
                );
$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );
```

Note that in order to send the same message to multiple registration IDs, the content type of the request must be JSON. The registration IDs are sent in a `registration_ids` parameter which contains an array, and the notification data is inside the `data` parameter which contains a dictionary.

Comment: I added the `$gcm->send_notification` to my original post. I use `CURL` in that code. Do I have to rewrite the whole php file in order to send to multiple devices?

Comment: @Jerome No, your `$gcm->send_notification` already handles sending to multiple registration IDs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put the array with the regIds into the JSON Object and put the JSON Objet in the Post:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair> ();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", JsonObject));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [GSON](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/files/google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip).

Now, to use, Create a class :

```
Class Messages {
    public String message;
    public ArrayList<String> regIDs;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getRegIDs() {
        return regIDs;
    }    
}
```

Now when you want to send some data to the server, create a new object of this class.

```
Messages messages = new Messages();
messages.setMessage("Some message here");
//Add all the regn IDs to the regIDs List. 
ArrayList<String> regIDs = messages.getRegIDs()
regIDs.add("regnID1");
regIDs.add("regnID2");
regIDs.add("regnID3");
regIDs.add("regnID4");

//Add as many IDs as you want. 
//then create a new GSON Object. 

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJSON(messages);
```

Now the `jsonString` will automatically contain a JSON String of the format you specified. So, send a POST Request to your server with the `jsonString` variable's content. Then on the Php side, use json_decode to decode into an array and traverse through the regIDs array to send multiple gcm messages.